# Update objects inside NESTED JSONB arrays with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Json Request:

```
INSERT INTO test.demotbl (data)
VALUES ('{
    "x1": "Americas",
    "x2": "West",
    "x3": [{
        "x_id": "sam"
    }],
    "x4": {
        "a1": true,
        "a2": false,
        "a3": [
            "xx",
            "xx"
        ],
        "a4": [
            "Josh"
        ],
        "y1": [{
                "id": "RW",
                "z2": true,
                "z3": "USER",
                "z4": [{
                    "name": "john"
                }]
            },
            {
                "id": "RO",
                "z2": false,
                "z3": "SELECT",
                "z4": [{
                    "name": "salin"
                }]
            }
        ]
    }
}'::jsonb)
```

I want to update the filed z4 based on id "id": "RO".

I had similar use case here when i needed to update the x3 field (but without any filter criteria)
I used :

```
UPDATE test.demotbl SET details = jsonb_set(data, '{x3}', [{"x_id": "sam"},{"x_id": "Rohit"}])
```

And request was updated successfully.
output:

```
{
    "x1": "Americas",
    "x2": "West",
    "x3": [{
        "x_id": "sam"
    },
    {
        "x_id": "Rohit"
    }],
    "x4": {
        "a1": true,
        "a2": false,
        "a3": [
            "xx",
            "xx"
        ],
        "a4": [
            "Josh"
        ],
        "y1": [{
                "id": "RW",
                "z2": true,
                "z3": "USER",
                "z4": [{
                    "name": "john"
                }]
            },
            {
                "id": "RO",
                "z2": false,
                "z3": "SELECT",
                "z4": [{
                    "name": "salin"
                }]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have similar use case ,now i need to update the z4 filed also based on id value ,the problem is the z4 element is nested and also i cant figure out how to put the filter condition.

Question : how can I  add/update the z4 where id is RW

Expected Output:

```
{
    "x1": "Americas",
    "x2": "West",
    "x3": [{
        "x_id": "sam"
    }],
    "x4": {
        "a1": true,
        "a2": false,
        "a3": [
            "xx",
            "xx"
        ],
        "a4": [
            "Josh"
        ],
        "y1": [{
                "id": "RW",
                "z2": true,
                "z3": "USER",
                "z4": [{
                    "name": "john"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Sandy"
                }]
            },
            {
                "id": "RO",
                "z2": false,
                "z3": "SELECT",
                "z4": [{
                    "name": "salin"
                }]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you might use something like this to update the field z3 to 'UPDATE' for example:

```
with zd as (select ('{x4,y1,'||index-1||',z3}')::text[] as path
            from table1
            ,jsonb_array_elements((field1->>'x4')::jsonb->'y1') 
            with ordinality arr(x,index)
            where x->>'id'='RO'
        )
update table1
set field1=jsonb_set(field1,zd.path,to_jsonb('UPDATE'::text),false)
from zd
```

This assumes the jsonb object is stored in table1, in field1 of type jsonb.
It also assumes there is only this one record in the table.

This code is taken from https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-update-objects-inside-jsonb-arrays-with-postgresql-5c4e03be256a/ and adjusted.

Best regards,
Bjarni

Comment: Thanks so much for the response Bjarni.The above solution you gave is updating filed z3 but i want to update filed z4.

Comment: The solution is very close can you please suggest /help to modify the query to update filed z4. Appreciate you help

Comment: i was able to modify the query to update filed z4.There is one problem which i missed earlier as well with the above query irrespective of filter condition x->>'id'=='RO' the query always updates the first array element of y1.(i.e the elemet with the field "id":"RW"

Comment: here is the query which i modified to update filed z4

Comment: with zd as (select ('{x4,y1,'||index-2||',z4}')::text[] as path
            from sandbox_service.demotbl
            ,jsonb_array_elements((data->>'x4')::jsonb->'y1')
            with ordinality arr(x,index)
            where x->>'id'='RO'
        )
update sandbox_service.demotbl
set data=jsonb_set(data,zd.path,to_jsonb('[
                    {
                        "name": "priyanka"
                    }
                ]'::jsonb),false)
from zd

Comment: Now the only problem is the filter condition during update ,can you please help me out in this ?

Comment: How were you planning to filter?  You should be able to add a where clause at the end of statement.

Comment: @ Bjarni Ragnarsson by filter here i mean the condition where x->>'id'='RO'.the  above query should update y1 ->z4 filed element where id='RO'

Comment: "y1": [{
                "id": "RW",
                "z2": true,
                "z3": "USER",
                "z4": [{
                    "name": "john"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Sandy"
                }]
            },
            {
                "id": "RO",
                "z2": false,
                "z3": "SELECT",
                "z4": [{
                    "name": "priyanka"
                }]
            }
        ]

Comment: But instead of the above the problem is it is updating the first array element only in y1->x4 filed

Comment: "y1": [{
                "id": "RW",
                "z2": true,
                "z3": "USER",
                "z4": [{
                    "name": "priyanka"
                }]
            },
            {
                "id": "RO",
                "z2": false,
                "z3": "SELECT",
                "z4": [{
                    "name": "salin"
                }]
            }
        ]

Comment: as you see above that filed z4 was updated where "id":"RW" which is wrong since we wanted the filed z4 to be updated where "id":"RO".

Comment: Replace RW with RO

Comment: the issue was in my updated query sorry to miss that which i updated i was using ...(select ('{x4,y1,'||index-2||',z4}')::text[] .... i changed to ..(select ('{x4,y1,'||index-1||',z4}')::text[]...Thank you  @Bjarni Ragnarsson for spending time to solve this !!!

Comment: No problem @PriyankaSahu

Comment: @ Bjarni Ragnarsson there couple  another requirement can you help me with question 1)the sql to upadate/delete the all values from y1 array where "id": "RO" from the above json ?Question 2) to only  delete value "id":RO"

Comment: @ Bjarni Ragnarsson Here  is the link for this question can you please take a look :   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59344017/delete-objects-inside-nested-jsonb-arrays-with-postgresql

Comment: HI @  Bjarni Ragnarsson extention to the above use case.The query works when i have to update field z4  but when trying to add when z4 is not present it does not work .Can you please suggest and help to modify the query so it works or both update and add a new filed z4 (when not present ). here is a separate thread i have opened for this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60350413/add-update-objects-and-elements-inside-nested-jsonb-arrays-with-postgresql  looking forward for your suggestion thanks in advance

Comment: @ Bjarni Ragnarsson i have opened another thread i think the above might be confusing so . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60352354/add-objects-inside-nested-jsonb-arrays-with-postgresql