# Delete objects inside NESTED JSONB arrays with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

json Request:

```
INSERT INTO test.demotbl (data)
VALUES ('{
    "x1": "Americas",
    "x2": "West",
    "x3": [{
        "x_id": "sam"
    }],
    "x4": {
        "a1": true,
        "a2": false,
        "a3": [
            "xx",
            "xx"
        ],
        "a4": [
            "Josh"
        ],
        "y1": [{
                "id": "RW",
                "z2": true,
                "z3": "USER",
                "z4": [{
                    "name": "john"
                }]
            },
             {
                "id": "RO",
                "z2": false,
                "z3": "SELECT",
                "z4": [{
                    "name": "salin"
                }
            {
                "id": "DBA",
                "z2": false,
                "z3": "SELECT",
                "z4": [{
                    "name": "Samule"
                }]
            }
        ]
    }
}'::jsonb)
```

Question 1 :how can i delete the the array values where  "id":"RO" from y1 array ?
There can be any no of element in the y1 json array i want to delete the array value based on id condition.

how can i delete the the array values where  "id":"RO" from y1 array ?
There can be any no of element in the y1 json array i want to delete the array value based on id condition.

Expected Output after deleting:

```
{
    "x1": "Americas",
    "x2": "West",
    "x3": [{
        "x_id": "sam"
    }],
    "x4": {
        "a1": true,
        "a2": false,
        "a3": [
            "xx",
            "xx"
        ],
        "a4": [
            "Josh"
        ],
        "y1": [{
                "id": "RW",
                "z2": true,
                "z3": "USER",
                "z4": [{
                    "name": "john"
                }]
            },

            {
                "id": "DBA",
                "z2": false,
                "z3": "SELECT",
                "z4": [{
                    "name": "Samule"
                }]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Question 2 : How can i only delete the "id":"RO" from the y1 array

Expected Output:

```
{
    "x1": "Americas",
    "x2": "West",
    "x3": [{
        "x_id": "sam"
    }],
    "x4": {
        "a1": true,
        "a2": false,
        "a3": [
            "xx",
            "xx"
        ],
        "a4": [
            "Josh"
        ],
        "y1": [{
                "id": "RW",
                "z2": true,
                "z3": "USER",
                "z4": [{
                    "name": "john"
                }]
            },
             {
                "z2": false,
                "z3": "SELECT",
                "z4": [{
                    "name": "salin"
                }
            {
                "id": "DBA",
                "z2": false,
                "z3": "SELECT",
                "z4": [{
                    "name": "Samule"
                }]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit note: I misunderstood the question.  Thought you wanted to delete the whole object containing 'RO'.  I edited the answer so as just to delete the id.

There is a small error in the jsonb object you provide.  It should probably look like this:

```
{
    "x1": "Americas",
    "x2": "West",
    "x3": [{
        "x_id": "sam"
    }],
    "x4": {
        "a1": true,
        "a2": false,
        "a3": [
            "xx",
            "xx"
        ],
        "a4": [
            "Josh"
        ],
        "y1": [{
                "id": "RW",
                "z2": true,
                "z3": "USER",
                "z4": [{
                    "name": "john"
                }]
            },
             {
                "id": "RO",
                "z2": false,
                "z3": "SELECT",
                "z4": [{
                    "name": "salin"
                }]
            },
            {
                "id": "DBA",
                "z2": false,
                "z3": "SELECT",
                "z4": [{
                    "name": "Samule"
                }]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

With that said, this should work, but keep in mind - this will replace all entries in the working table.  The jsonb objects are in the field "field".

```
with zd as (select ('{x4,y1,'||index-1||',id}')::text[] as path
            from table
            ,jsonb_array_elements((field->>'x4')::jsonb->'y1') 
            with ordinality arr(x,index)
            where x->>'id'='RO'
        )
        update table set field=
        field #- zd.path 
        from zd
```

Best regards,
Bjarni

Comment: Thanks @Bjarni Ragnarsson that solves the Question 2.For Question 1 i want to delete the entire this value ==> {
                "id": "RO",
                "z2": false,
                "z3": "SELECT",
                "z4": [{
                    "name": "salin"
                }

Comment: yes i wanted to delete the whole object containing 'RO' that is my first question .Second question was to just delete "id":"RO" which you have provided the solution :)

Comment: Ok.  To delete the whole object, replace "with zd as (select ('{x4,y1,'||index-1||',id}')::text[] as path" with "with zd as (select ('{x4,y1,'||index-1||'}')::text[] as path".

Comment: Awesome that solves it.Thanks again for the solution @ Bjarni Ragnarsson